# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 with django.setup()

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

My initial problem was `models not loaded yet` and somehow I got info from stackoverflow that `django.setup()` solves the issue. But then again when I use `django.setup()` I get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10
```

Here is my traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Samson/Documents/searchengine/SearchEngine/Scripts/lens/lens/crawler.py", line 110, in <module>
    spider.crawl_web()
  File "C:/Users/Samson/Documents/searchengine/SearchEngine/Scripts/lens/lens/crawler.py", line 66, in crawl_web
    objListing.save() #save to database
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 591, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 619, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 681, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 711, in _do_update
    filtered = base_qs.filter(pk=pk_val)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 691, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 709, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1287, in add_q
    clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1314, in _add_q
    current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1186, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1094, in build_lookup
    return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 82, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 85, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_lookup(self.lookup_name, self.rhs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 646, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 915, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5617c8f4b705960e4c314406'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `django.setup()`. The error is happening in `crawl_web`: you are trying to save an item with an integer field, but giving it the value "5617c8f4b705960e4c314406" which is not an integer.

Comment: then it's probable the _id field (which is specified automatically) that is the problem. I don't know why it is being stored in an integer field, can you please help